# On button click slide and focus on search input in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, focus, opera-mobile

I have made this UI with jquery mobile, here i am doing is on button click a search input slide down for search... and likewise it will focus on the input box...

This is the script i am using,

```
 $(function() {

    $( ".opensearch" ).on( 'tap', tapHandler );

    function tapHandler( event ) {
      $('.search_field').slideToggle();
      setTimeout(function(){
         $('.search').focus().tap();
        },0);
    }

});
```

I have tested it on **Opera Mobile and iphone** but the problem is that the focus doesnt happen means it should show the *browser keyboard* if applied `focus()` on it...

Is my code correct or something else? Is pure javascript is the solution for making this work?

Here is a non-working demo of it, http://jsfiddle.net/aH4QM/show/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just converted `type="search"` to `type="text"` in my html code and added a submit button for the search...

Like that:-

```
<form>
      <input name="search" class="search" value="" placeholder="Search Item...." type="text" data-theme="e">
      <input type="submit" value="Search" data-mini="false" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c"  />
</form>
```

And JS as usual a simple one for focus:-

```
$( ".opensearch" ).on( 'click', tapHandler );
function tapHandler( event ) {
     $('.search_field').toggle();
     $('.search').focus();
}
```

The code is now working for me...
http://jsfiddle.net/aH4QM/14/show/

Answer (score 4):

Issue in your code is  `$('.search').focus().tap();`

In html you mentioned

```
 <input name="search" id="search" value="" placeholder="Search Item...." type="search" data-theme="e" />
```

`'Id'` should start with `'#' not '.'`

Modified jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/aH4QM/4/

Note: To check in fiddle I changed the `'tap'`event to`'click'`

Comment: thanks for the reply, your right but focus on search input is not working in opera mobile and iphone as i mentioned...

Answer (score 0):

when you accessing particular element through id you have to use "#" not "." and when u accessing the element through class name that time you can use  ".". Please refer below code.

```
$(function() {

    $( ".opensearch" ).on( 'tap', tapHandler );

    function tapHandler( event ) {
      $('.search_field').slideToggle();
      setTimeout(function(){
         $('#search').focus().tap();
        },0);
    }

});
```

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: focus on search input is not working in opera mobile and iphone as i mentioned...